react-native-reanimated component is working in react-native 0.74 but in react-native 0.76
This is BottomTabNavigator.js file:
const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const { height } = Dimensions.get('window');
const SNAP_TOP = height + StatusBar.currentHeight;
const SNAP_BOTTOM = 54 + 50;
    
const BottomTabNavigator = () => {
    const yValue = useSharedValue(SNAP_BOTTOM);
    return (
        <>
          {/* this component contain all screen and bottom tab navigator */}
            <BottomTab.Navigator
                tabBar={(props) => <BottomTabBar {...props} yValue={yValue} snapTop={SNAP_TOP} snapBottom={SNAP_BOTTOM} />}
                initialRouteName="Home"   // "Home" initial screen to render 
                backBehavior="history"
                screenOptions={{
                    headerShown: false,
                    tabBarHideOnKeyboard: true,
                }}
            >
                <BottomTab.Screen
                    name="Home"
                    component={Home}
                    options={{
                        tabBarLabel: "Home",
                        // we are importing focused as well as size from BottomTabBar.js file
                        tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <HomeIcon height={icon_size} width={icon_size} fill={color} />,
                    }}
                />
                <BottomTab.Screen
                    name="Search"
                    component={Search}
                    options={{
                        tabBarLabel: "Search",
                        tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <SearchIcon height={icon_size} width={icon_size} fill={color} />
                    }}
                />
            </BottomTab.Navigator>
            {/* this component contains the mini player & player page */}
            <SlidingBottom yValue={yValue} snapTop={SNAP_TOP} snapBottom={SNAP_BOTTOM} />
        </>
    );
}

export default BottomTabNavigator;

This is SlidingBottom.js file:
const { height } = Dimensions.get('window');
const SNAP_TOP = height + StatusBar.currentHeight;
const SNAP_BOTTOM = 54 + 50;
const config = {
    damping: 15,
    mass: 1,
    stiffness: 120,
    restSpeedThreshold: 0.1,
    restDisplacementThreshold: 0.1,
}

const SlidingBottom = ({ yValue }) => {
    // const yValue = useSharedValue(SNAP_BOTTOM);
    const prevYValue = useSharedValue(SNAP_BOTTOM);
    const pan = Gesture.Pan().minDistance(1).onBegin(() => {
        prevYValue.value = yValue.value;
    }).onUpdate((evevnt) => {
        yValue.value = clamp(
            prevYValue.value - evevnt.translationY,
            SNAP_BOTTOM,
            SNAP_TOP
        );
    }).onEnd((evevnt) => {
        yValue.value = withSpring(
            snapPoints(
                clamp(
                    prevYValue.value - evevnt.translationY,
                    SNAP_BOTTOM,
                    SNAP_TOP
                ),
                -evevnt.velocityY,
                [SNAP_BOTTOM, SNAP_TOP]),
            config
        );
    }).runOnJS(true);

    const yStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
        height: yValue.value
    }))

    const oStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
        opacity: interpolate(yValue.value, [SNAP_TOP, SNAP_BOTTOM], [0, 1], Extrapolation.CLAMP)
    }))

    return (
        <GestureDetector gesture={pan}>
            <Animated.View style={[yStyle, { position: "absolute", left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, backgroundColor: "red", borderColor: "purple", borderWidth: 1, zIndex: layout_schema.zIndexForSlidingBottom }]}>
                <Animated.View style={[oStyle, { height: 50, backgroundColor: "mediumseagreen" }]} />
                <Player />
            </Animated.View>
        </GestureDetector>
    );
}

export default SlidingBottom;

This is BottomTabBar.js file:
import { useEffect, useState, useMemo } from "react";
import { Dimensions, Keyboard, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, StatusBar, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { useTheme } from "@react-navigation/native";
import Animated, { Extrapolation, interpolate, useSharedValue, useAnimatedStyle, withTiming, Easing } from "react-native-reanimated";
// import constants
import { color_schema, icon_size, layout_schema } from "../../constants/constants";

const { height } = Dimensions.get('window');

const BottomTabBar = ({ state, descriptors, navigation, yValue, snapTop, snapBottom }) => {    
    // using this hook we can get all colors used by react navigation 
    // as hooks can be only called inside function that's why we cannot declare all styles in StyleSheet
    const { colors } = useTheme();

    // this is used to check if keyboard is visible or not
    const [keyboardVisible, setKeyboardVisible] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        const keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener("keyboardDidShow", () => {
            //Whenever keyboard did show make it don't visible
            setKeyboardVisible(false);
        });
        const keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener("keyboardDidHide", () => {
            setKeyboardVisible(true);
        });
        return () => {
            keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
            keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
        };
    }, [])

    const bStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
        // height: interpolate(yValue.value, [snapTop, snapBottom], [0, 54], Extrapolation.CLAMP), then add bottom: 0 in styles.bottom
        bottom: interpolate(yValue.value, [snapTop, snapBottom], [-54, 0], Extrapolation.CLAMP)
    }));

    return (
        keyboardVisible &&
        <Animated.View style={[styles.bottom, bStyle, { backgroundColor: colors.card }]}>
            {
                state.routes.map((route, index) => {
                    const { options } = descriptors[route.key];
                    const label = options.tabBarLabel !== undefined
                        ? options.tabBarLabel
                        : options.title !== undefined
                            ? options.title
                            : route.name;
                    const isFocused = useMemo(() => state.index === index, [state.index]);

                    {/* function for onPress event */ }
                    const onPress = () => {
                        const event = navigation.emit({
                            type: "tabPress",
                            target: route.key,
                        });
                        if (!isFocused && !event.defaultPrevented) {
                            navigation.navigate(route.name);
                        }
                    };

                    {/* function for onLongPress event */ }
                    const onLongPress = () => {
                        const event = navigation.emit({
                            type: "tabLongPress",
                            target: route.key,
                        });
                        if (!isFocused && !event.defaultPrevented) {
                            navigation.navigate(route.name);
                        }
                    };

                    {/* setting color for icon and text */ }
                    const color = isFocused ? color_schema.focused_header_color : color_schema.unfocused_header_color
                    const widthSharedValue = useSharedValue(isFocused ? "100%" : "0%");

                    useEffect(() => {
                        widthSharedValue.value = withTiming(isFocused ? "100%" : "0%", {
                            duration: 300,
                            easing: Easing.bounce,
                        })
                    }, [state.index])

                    const animatedWidth = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
                        'worklet';
                        return {
                            width: widthSharedValue.value,
                        };
                    })

                    return (
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            key={route.key} // using route.key for unique keys but we can use index also
                            // accessibilityRole="button"
                            accessibilityState={isFocused ? { selected: true } : {}}
                            accessibilityLabel={options.tabBarAccessibilityLabel}
                            testID={options.tabBarTestID}
                            onPress={onPress}
                            onLongPress={onLongPress}
                        >
                            <View style={styles.navItem}>
                            {/* this view contains icon */}
                            <View>
                                    {options.tabBarIcon({ color, focused: isFocused, size: icon_size })}
                                </View>
                            {/* this view contains label */}
                            <View style={styles.labelContainer}>
                                    <Text style={[styles.label, { color }]}>{label}</Text>
                                </View>
                            {/* this view contains undedrline */}
                            <Animated.View style={[styles.underline, animatedWidth]} />
                            </View>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    );
                })
            }
        </Animated.View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    bottom: {
        borderTopColor: color_schema.border_bottom_color,
        borderTopWidth: 1,
        flexDirection: "row",
        justifyContent: "space-evenly",
        alignItems: "center",
        paddingTop: 5,
        paddingBottom: 2,
        position: "absolute",
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        zIndex: layout_schema.zIndexForBottomTabNavigator,
        height: 54,
        overflow: "hidden",
    },
    navItem: {
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        width: "100%",
    },
    labelContainer: {
        marginTop: -1,
        marginBottom: 1,
        marginHorizontal: "auto",
        width: "auto",
    },
    label: {
        fontSize: 10,
        fontWeight: "400",
    },
    underline: {
        backgroundColor: color_schema.focused_header_color,
        borderRadius: 2,
        height: 2,
    },
});

export default BottomTabBar;

This code works fine in RN 0.74, but not in RN 0.76. In RN 0.76, height is not changing on initial render, but when I click on some other tab, it works fine. I tried to debug but cannot find the reason.
Also, the reason I want to jump to RN 0.76 it due to its new architecture.
I know there are other npm packages like this, but I am skeptical in using those pacakges.
Kindly help me react-native community.
